# How do I remove the long distance port configuration on a brocade port?

Tags: storage, storage-area-network, brocade

I have recently consolidated ISL ports on a brocade switch, and am trying to reclaim ports that are no longer connecting the switches. The one part I'm not sure about is how to get rid of the long distance parameter (in my case, LS). For example, to set up an ISL, I would execute:

```
portcfglongdistance 0 LS 1 25
```

A portcfgshow shows me:

```
Ports of Slot 0    0   1   2   3 
-----------------+---+---+---+---
...
Long Distance      LS  ..  ..  ..
VC Link Init       ON  ..  ..  ..
...
```

How can I change that "LS" back to ".."? The [manual page](http://www.brocade.com/downloads/documents/html_product_manuals/FOS_CMDREF_701/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm#context=53-1002447-01&file=commands_a_z.4.265.html) for portcfglongdistance offers me the choice between: L0, LE, LD, and LS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looks like L0. from the manual:

```
Specify L0 to configure the port as a regular port.
```

or you could also reset the port to factory defaults: http://www.brocade.com/downloads/documents/html_product_manuals/FOS_CMDREF_701/commands_a_z.4.253.html

Comment: L0 is what I would use to make an ISL within the same datacenter, though- is that the same as an F-port? edit: in the manual, it states: "Specify  L0  to  configure the port as a regular port. A total of 20 full size frame buffers will be  reserved  for data traffic regardless of the port's operating speed.  Therefore, the  maximum supported  link  distance  is  up  to 10 Km at 1 Gbps, up to 5 Km at 2 Gbps, up  to  2  Km  at  4 Gbps,  and up to 1 km at 8 Gbps, respectively". All my other F-ports only have 8 buffer credits.

Comment: I checked it out, and you're absolutely right. I used portcfglongdistance 0 L0, and it worked like a charm. Thanks :)